# How to count two different values and not stopping the same time

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery.countTo to count two different values but the issue is, the count start at the same time and stop at the same time even though the values are different. How can I start the count at the same time and stop when the value reaches its peak. for example, 216 should stop when it reaches 216 whilst 249 keeps counting until it reaches 249. Thanks

```
$('#cat-'+catNum+' span#asp-1-ev').countTo({from: 1,to: 249,speed:50000});
$('#cat-'+catNum+' span#asp-2-ev').countTo({from: 1,to: 216,speed:50000});
```

Comment: Numeric-indexed IDs are a code smell - consider using classes instead.

Comment: Ok got that, but any help about the question asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `speed` option defines how long it should take to reach the finish. Since you put the same value for both counters, they will finish at the same time.

See [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-countto#options):

> speed  | data-speed | The number of milliseconds it should take to finish counting. (default: 1000)

If you want the increments in both widgets to happen with equal intervals, then you could calculate this `speed` option dynamically:

```
const speed = 200;
$('#a').countTo({from: 1, to: 249, speed: 249*speed});
$('#b').countTo({from: 1, to: 216, speed: 216*speed});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution  and it worked perfectly.